# Convergence in $L^1([a,b])$ of $n \left(f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right) - f(x)\right)$ to the weak derivative of $f \in W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f \in W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $f' \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ its weak derivative. Let $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded interval.

How do I prove that $$\left\Vert n \left(f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right) - f(x)\right) - f' \right\Vert_{L^1([a,b])} \to 0?$$

Comment: That depends a lot on how much you know about Sobolev spaces beyond basic definitions.

Comment: @UmbertoP. What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints. Observe first that
$$
n\left(f\left(x+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(x)\right)-f'(x)=n\int_0^{1/n}\left(f'(x+s)-f'(x)\right)\,ds,
$$
and hence
$$
\left\|n\left(f\left(n+\frac{1}{n}\right)-f(x)\right)-f'(x)\,\right\|_{L^1[a,b]}
\le n\int_a^b \int_0^{1/n}\left|\,f'(x+s)-f'(x)\right|\,ds\,dx \\=n\int_0^{1/n} \int_a^b\left|\,f'(x+s)-f'(x)\right|\,dx\,ds=n\int_0^{1/n}\|\tau_s f'-f'\|_{L^1[a,b]}\,ds,
$$
where $(\tau_s g)(x)=g(x+s)$.
It suffices now to show that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$, such that
$$
0\le s <\delta\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \|\tau_sg-g\|_{L^1[a,b]}<\varepsilon,
$$
which is a standard result, which follows from the fact that the continuous functions are dense in $L^1$ - For a proof see for example PDEs by Folland.

If $1/n<\delta$, then $\int_0^{1/n}\|\tau_sf'-f'\|\,ds\le \varepsilon/n.$
$$
$$

Comment: Where did you use $f \in C^1$?

Comment: @Riku Actually, I did not use it!

Comment: I see. Thanks. Also, the last statement is not clear to me: It suffices now to show that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$, such that
$$
0\le s <\delta\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \|\tau_sg-g\|_{L^1[a,b]}<\varepsilon,
$$
which is a standard result.

Comment: Why does this imply our result and how does one prove the "standard result" about translations?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer was really helpful.

Comment: Another question: why can you apply Fubini's theorem and exchange the two integrals?